# Prevent UISplitViewController Master View from hiding (iPad iOS 4.x)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xamarin.ios

All worked fine in iOS 3.x on the iPad to prevent the Master view of the UISplitViewController from hiding.  I created a method SizeControls() that was called whenever the device rotated (WillAnimateRotation event).

Now with iOS 4 on the iPad this no longer works.  While the SizeControls is called something is still causing the Master view to be hidden.  What do I need to do so that on both iOS 3 and iOS 4 I can have both Master and Details views appear just like in the Settings UI?

Thank you.

Comment: My SizeControls() code is:
  private void SizeControls()
  {
   UIViewController master = ViewControllers[0];
   UIViewController detail = ViewControllers[1];
   master.View.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 320, this.View.Bounds.Height);
   detail.View.Frame = new RectangleF(321, 0, this.View.Bounds.Width - 321, this.View.Bounds.Height);
  }

Comment: I agree this is very annoying, I don't need the extra screen space. No easy way to do this really, tried to make a splitviewcontroller myself that was a container view controller, PAIN PAIN PAIN. I'm most ineterested in finding out what is actually hiding the master view so we can find someway to un-hide it.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html), apple recommends you show the master view in a popover when in portrait.

If thats not a goer take a look at MGSplitViewController.  Its a very nice split view which gives you this functionality for free.

Comment: Also here: old pos, but I have ported the MGSplitViewController to Monotouch. It is called MTSplitViewController and can be found here: https://github.com/Krumelur/MTSplitViewController